# Как результат функции вывести в DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookie

```js
var x = 0;

function actln2() {
  x = x + 1;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="actln2()">как сюда вывести x?</div>
```

Comment: Если бы все называли свои темы "помогите с кодом", Вы сами смогли бы быстро найти нужный вопрос среди тысяч одинаковых названий? В названии должен быть отражен СМЫСЛ ЗАДАЧИ

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = 0;

function actln2() {
  x = x + 1;
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="actln2()">как сюда вывести x?</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = 0;

function actln2(div) {
  x = x + 1;
  div.innerText = x;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="actln2(this)">как сюда вывести x?</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

как сюда вывести x?

```
const div = document.querySelector('#div')
let x = 0;

div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    div.innerHTML = calc();
});

function calc() {
    return x = x + 1;
}
```

В общем тоже самое что и писали до этого, только лучше навешивать события не в html, а в js... И разбивать функции одна считает, другая добавляет элемент в DOM.